# How to show a validationmessage on the validation of two fields and make the form invalid

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I want to make a validation on the sum of two fields, both are numeric input, but the total must not be larger than 100.

So I thought I'd make a `hidden input` which reads the total from my controller, and create a custom `validationdirective` to check the value to be <= 100 and create a span which checks whether that input is valid or not and then show/hide it.

But the input is bound to a function (which adds the two fields together) on my controller, so I can not use ng-model.
So I thought I use ng-bind, but then my validation directive complained about this:
`require: 'ngModel',`, because I don't have a ng-model anymore.

So I deleted that `require`, but then the `ctrl.$validators` was not present anymore and that gave me an error....

And now I am lost :-)

My validationdirective is this:

```
angular.module(Config.name).directive('maxvalue', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$validators.maxvalue = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                //validation here

            };
        }
    };
});
```

Can you give my a way to solve this?

EDIT

maybe my question is broader: I have more of these like alidations, where the validation is not tied to a single input field. I also have two buttons which a user can click (sort of a radio button, but then implemented with 2 buttons). I also want to show a span when no button is clicked + make the form invalid.

But I do not know how to say to the form 'you are invalid' neither from the form itself neither from the controller.

Comment: Why not use `ngChange` on both fields with method that will check if sum of both models exceeds 100 and then set form and both fields invalid (so user knows what's wrong)

Comment: How can I set the form and field invalid? Do you have some code? I don't know how to set the form and field invalid, apart from doing it from a directive....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For set form or input valid\invalid you can use [$setValidity](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

But i recommend use special library [use-form-error](https://github.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error).

Example of using you can see on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/w2um1d4n/)

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', ['use', 'ngMessages'])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {

  });
```

```css
.errors {
  color: maroon
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error/master/src/use-form-error.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <form name="myForm">
      <label>Enter your digit 1:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="digit1" name="myDigit1" />
      <br>
       <label>Enter your digit 2:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="digit2" name="myDigit3"  />

     
       <div  use-form-error="isGeaterHundred" use-error-expression="digit1*1+digit2*1>100" ng-messages="myForm.$error" class="errors">
        <div ng-message="isGeaterHundred">Your sum is greated then 100</div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">
    </form>
    
  </div>
</div>
```